# Dart test - Equivalent of `flutter_test_config.dart`

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-test

I'm writing tests for a dart package.

With [`flutter_test`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/flutter_test-library.html), it is possible to define one or several `flutter_test_config.dart` configuration files.

Is there something similar with dart tests?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [dart_test.yaml](https://pub.dev/packages/test#whole-package-configuration). Docs can be found [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/blob/master/pkgs/test/doc/configuration.md).